# How to set up queue Reassignment

Tags: queue, service-console, custom-service-console

I have an issue whereby which, if an employee changes the ownership of a case in our Service Console that it doesn't change queues. For example: I change ownership from client services to helpdesk queues, the case actually stays in client services queue but also gets opened in the help desk queue at the same time.

Any idea how to set this up? I have found a lot of documentation on how to set up queues, icons, actions, buttons, but no real documentation on how changing ownership should move from one queue to the other. As a result I am trying to automate the case management within our Service console.

Comment: Seems like queue is going back to the origin queue. It can be due to some customization in your org which is rolling back the transaction. Suggest you to setup the debug log (look for exception/error) and share the same here so that we can find out the problem.

Comment: There could be a workflow rule or process builder changing the ownership - check if those exist.

Comment: Yeah we found the issue workflow rules and maps were not set up from the get-go. I am dealing with a big mess so we started over from scratch.